# Ajax call in mvc5 always returning error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My controller action (in AjaxMethodsController )  is:

```
public ActionResult CreateGroup(String groupName)
        {
            ApplicationUser user;
            var userName = User.Identity.Name;
            using (DAL.GDContext context = new DAL.GDContext())
            {
                user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);                              
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var group = new Group();
                    group.GroupName = "test";
                    group.Members.Add(user);

                    context.Groups.Add(group);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

which should simply create the group with the group name specified. My ajax and jquery code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#CreateGroup').on("click", function () {
        var groupName = "testgroup";
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AjaxMethods/CreateGroup",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'GroupName': groupName }),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error has occured!!!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It always returns the "An error has occured!!!" message. Furthermore to this question, how do I set it to always return as an error if the group was not created (possibly with reason why i.e. group name already exists). I don't want the page to redirect after... am i supposed to use JsonResult instead of ActionResult?
I am new to ajax, as of about an hour so explanations rather than just code would be really helpful! thank you!

Update #1: new CreateGroup

```
public JsonResult CreateGroup(String GroupName)
        {
            ApplicationUser user;
            var userName = User.Identity.Name;
            using (DAL.GDContext context = new DAL.GDContext())
            {
                user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);                              
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var group = new Group();
                    group.GroupName = GroupName;
                    group.Members.Add(user);

                    context.Groups.Add(group);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            string result = userName;
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax call will receive the content of the view in the way you are using it. You probally want to return the data in Json to your ajax request if you are not interested in rendering the result as markup.

```
 string result="OK";
 return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried what's put in update #1 but still getting an error

Comment: Could you set the url using '@Url.Action("CreateGroups","AjaxMethods")' and I don't think you need the JSON.Stringify as it will be sent over in json format by default you can just use data:{'GroupName':groupName}

Comment: tried, i get this in F12 dev tools:
POST http://localhost:49782/AjaxMethods/CreateGroup 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Look at the response body. There should be more details. Also, if you put a breakpoint on your controller method you can more than likely trace into the error.

Comment: ah it wasnt using the right controller method! Seems to work now, thanks! Is there a way to define ajax post above the controller? Like there's [HttpPost], is there an ajax version?

Comment: no, a post using ajax is a http post. However, you can always use HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() to determine if the post/get was made using an ajax call.

Comment: ah ok thanks! Further question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459037/do-you-need-to-use-two-calls-1-get-and-1-post-in-ajax-or-can-you-send-data-bac
If you can :)