# Do you need to use two calls - 1 get and 1 post in ajax or can you send data back with the success / failure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following controller method:

```
    public JsonResult CreateGroup(String GroupName)
            {
                ApplicationUser user;
                var userName = User.Identity.Name;
                using (DAL.GDContext context = new DAL.GDContext())
                {
                    user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);                              
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var group = new Group();
                        group.GroupName = GroupName;
                        group.Members.Add(user);

                        context.Groups.Add(group);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                string result = userName;
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
            }

with the following ajax call:

$(function () {
        $('#CreateGroup').on("click", function () {

            var groupName = $('#groupname').val();
            if (groupName != '') {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("CreateGroup","AjaxMethods")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'GroupName': groupName }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                        CreateGroup(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("An error has occured!!!");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The CreateGroup function fails saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Do i have to use another Json request - type post - to get the username?

Comment: Try using `type : "GET"`

Comment: data is probably 'undefined'.  Are you positive that you are getting a return object from the ajax call.  Are you sure the server is getting your POST?  What other debugging have you done?

Comment: Hi, the post definately works, but I don't know if you can also retrieve data (ie the username) in the same call... that's my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the call without using JSON.stringify. Also your controller method has a cache attribute that may yield more control. Personally, I would use the controller cache control.  You are probably getting a cached version of the controller call prior to returning data.

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
 public ActionResult CreateGroup(string GroupName)



$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CreateGroup","AjaxMethods")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'GroupName': groupName },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,    
    success: function (data, status, xhr ) {
        alert("success");
        CreateGroup(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("An error has occured!!!");
    }
});
```

NOTE: Update success callback.

Comment: Thanks again! Would you mind explaining the xhr variable? I assume status is just the status of the request? Also, I always get failiure without the Json.Stringify() which is why i added back in - just checked again and it still fails without it. The update the sucess function works perfectly though, thank you!